# leaflet maps - remove marker layer group and add another marker layer group

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, marker

My objective here is to remove all the markers added to leaflet using layer group for a paginated listing page.When navigated to other page i am able to remove layer group of previous page, but on adding new layer group of markers(markers of next page) i am getting this error in browser and markers are not added to the map

error is - Uncaught TypeError: layer.onAdd is not a function;

code is

```
var leaflet_factory = {
    //initializing map container
    initialize: function() {
        var map = L.map('mapresults');
        var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
        map.addLayer(googleLayer);
    },

    //set view of mao
    setview: function(lat, long, zoom) {

        map.setView([lat, long], zoom);

    },

    //add list of markers to maps

    addMarkersList: function(marker_array) {
        var markerArray = [];
        $.each(marker_array, function(key, data) {
            var marker_pointer = L.marker([data.lat, data.long]).bindPopup('<a href="/' + $(this).attr('data-slug') + '"><strong>' + $(this).attr('data-vendor').capitalize() + '</strong><br></a>' + $(this).attr('data-location').capitalize());
            markerArray.push(marker_pointer);
        });
        window.page_makers_layer = L.layerGroup(markerArray);
        window.page_makers_layer.addTo(map);

    },

    //remove the current marker layer group

    removeMarkerLayer: function() {

        map.removeLayer(window.page_makers_layer);

    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is when calling addMarkersList for first time after initializing the map container it works.
But when i call addMarkerList with new list of markers(lat long pair) after calling removeMarkerLayer to remove existing marker layer it gives me following error which i am trying to debug.

```
Uncaught TypeError: layer.onAdd is not a function
```

Please point where i am doing wrong.

Comment: There is still not enough information to help you. Anyway, it is very strange that you define your `map` within `initialize` scope only.

Comment: yeah, it is bad.but this is not the actual code that i have in production.The actual code is even more worst written by some other guy who is now not part of the team.Thanks anyway for educating me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong. Not catastrophically wrong, just antipattern wrong, e.g.:

```
map.removeLayer(window.page_makers_layer);
```

Do **NOT** use window globals to store references to your data (unless you're really, really, really sure of what you're doing). If you're wrapping map creation in a factory or a module, store your data in that scope.

```
var leaflet_factory = {
```

Do not name something a factory if it doesn't follow the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). It's *very* confusing. Just name it differently, make it a CJS module instead, or skip it entirely.

Research into common programming patterns. Do you have something that appears only once in the webpage? Consider singletons.

> gives me following error which I am trying to debug.

How are you trying to debug it? Learn to use your browser debugging capabilities, and provide a complete stack trace.

You should be able to easily keep track of the value of the problematic variable, and see if it is an instance of `L.LayerGroup` when the call is made.